# How to use docusaurus with Fluent UI?

Tags: javascript, server-side-rendering, docusaurus, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I am now working on Docusaurus (which is a static site generator) with Fluent UI, and I don't know how to setup SSR for Fluent UI, there's no any useful information on Internet.

What I've known:

Fluent UI use a lib called merge-styles to achieve its CSS-in-JS support. merge-styles will generate CSS class for each style set, and these classes must be written into HTML `<head></head>` tag to be active. This lib uses an ID counter which will add an ID suffix to each class. In general, both `mergeStyles` and `mergeStyleSets` call will generate some CSS classes, and in server-side and client-side, the value of ID counter may be different. Docusaurus is a pure static site generator which has a building bundle without any server code. It will pre-execute all codes on building and uses the result of each page as final generated html file. So, in building process, Fluent UI seems generated a set of stylesheets with a set of IDs, and if I use:

```js
import {Stylesheet, resetIds} from "@fluentui/react";

// These codes are run on the server side.
resetIds();
let stylesheet = Stylesheet.getInstance();
let serializedStylesheet = stylesheet.serialize();
let rules = stylesheet.getRules(true);

// Inject rules into generated codes as <style data-merge-styles="true">{rules}</style>

let script = `
    window.FabricConfig = window.FabricConfig || {};
    window.FabricConfig.serializedStylesheet = ${serializedStylesheet};
`;

// Inject script into generated codes as <script>{script}</script>
```

I actually will get another set of classNames and rules with totally different ID, and that makes my page looks a mess.

I saw another way is `renderStatic`, but I think I cannot use it because I cannot get the real root component of Docusaurus page.

I know that Stylesheet is an object which is registered in a variable named `_global`, and this variable is initialized in the file `Stylesheet.ts`. This initialization process will first check if there is an object called `window.FabricConfig` and then assign it or an empty object to `_global`. When we call `getInstance()`, this function will search `_global` for an existing Stylesheet object, and if there's no such object, it will initialize a brand new instance with all properties have a same value `{}`. So, what is confusing me is:

1. Why the client uses a new Stylesheet object instead of the one I've already injected to the page's window? (I can make sure that the injected codes are executed **before** all other scripts)
2. The Stylesheet object is initialized with all properties are `{}`, so, where the values of Stylesheet object that I injected come from?
3. How could I get the actual Stylesheet object used in server-side rendering?

I hope there could be some experts of this question could do me a favour. Thanks.